# How to convert array of items to array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How to convert array of items like:

```
var arrayOfItems = [item1, item2, item3];
```

to array of objects like:

```
var arrayOfObjects = [{0: item1}, {1: item2}, {2: item3}];
```

?? Is there any way to add item to an array and immediately set additional property of the item? Or I need convert it to the object and then add property?

Comment: Why???? That makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const arrayOfObjects = arrayOfItems.map((item, index) => ({[index]: item}))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 arrayOfItems.map((v, i) => ({ [i]: v }));
```

Just map your array to a new one that uses the index as a key and takes over the arrays value as its value.

Comment: thanks, I was thinking of orray of objects like var arrayOfObjects = [ 0 {0: item1}, 1 {1: item2}, 2 {2: item3}];